# Encode xml from structs

Tags: xml, go, struct

I'm new to go and trying to get the following piece of code to work with no luck. Looks like I don't have the struct of structs part correctly coded. Help!

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    type Person struct {
        Email string `xml:"email"`
        Phone string `xml:"phone"`
    }

    type Host struct {
        Hostname string `xml:"hostname"`
        Address  string `xml:"address"`
    }

    type Asset struct {
        person Person
        host   Host
    }

    p := &Person{Email: "person@a.com", Phone: "1111"}
    h := &Host{Hostname: "boxen", Address: "1 Place St"}
    a := &Asset{person: *p, host: *h}

    enc := xml.NewEncoder(os.Stdout)
    enc.Indent(" ", " ")
    if err := enc.Encode(p); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v\n", err)
    }
    if err := enc.Encode(h); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v\n", err)
    }
    if err := enc.Encode(a); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v\n", err)
    }
}
```

[Go playground here](https://play.golang.org/p/BIoKj4Uy_F)

Expected output. What I currently get is an empty Asset element.

```
 <Asset>
   <Person>
    <email>person@a.com</email>
    <phone>1111</phone>
   </Person>
   <Host>
    <hostname>boxen</hostname>
    <address>1 Place St</address>
   </Host>
 </Asset>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? In what way does it not work, what did you want it to do and what does it actually do?

Comment: I second what @Adrian said, but also to do any encoding/decoding you have to export your fields, which Asset does not have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must export the properties of the "Asset" type by making their names start with a capital letter:

```
type Asset struct {
  Person Person
  Host   Host
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As long as `person` and `host` are unexported, there is no way for `enc.Encode` to know about them. Exporting them will give your desired output.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    type Person struct {
        Email string `xml:"email"`
        Phone string `xml:"phone"`
    }

    type Host struct {
        Hostname string `xml:"hostname"`
        Address  string `xml:"address"`
    }

    type Asset struct {
        Person Person
        Host   Host
    }

    p := &Person{Email: "person@a.com", Phone: "1111"}
    h := &Host{Hostname: "boxen", Address: "1 Place St"}
    a := &Asset{Person: *p, Host: *h}

    enc := xml.NewEncoder(os.Stdout)
    enc.Indent(" ", " ")

    if err := enc.Encode(a); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v\n", err)
    }
}
```